# HP J8156A Vernier network adapter

Tags: power-supply, network-adapter, connector

I've got a network card, that may or may not be working that I am trying to use in my home server. Got it from ebay as "used".The card does not let the computer boot, the computer turns on, but nothing happens. The card is PCI one and has this weird white connector which I believe is the one casing the problem. The problem is I don't recognize it, there is no similar connector on PSU and I can't seem to find anything about it in google. So I've made 2 photos of the connector, the [front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUsl5.jpg) and the [legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEvhP.jpg), maybe someone here would have the experience to identify it and direct me to a manual of sort.
Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the pinout legend, that is not a power connector, so DO NOT connect it to the PSU. I think the connector is not normally used by default unless you have some especial purpose for it. So the problem might lies somewhere -probably improper seating, IRQ conflict, card is defective, etc.

Comment: @miggy oh, okay, the +5v and +3.3vr confused me. Okay then, must be some other reason for the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have at similar card with the same connector. I have figured out that it is a ProCurve Secure Access 700wl 4-Port 10/100 Card (J8156A). This was made for HP smart switch or router.

Regarding the connector: I don’t know. I would not try to force a random contactor inn to it.

Are you sure that the card does not shows up in windows management console (perhaps as an unknown devise)?

I have not tested my card